# How to make fair gas consumption of smart contract users

Tags: solidity, ether, remix, myetherwallet

i have made a contract that 2 users participate in the smart contract, both users do the same steps however i notice it that user1 pay more gas ( transaction gas and execution gas ) than user 2

any idea to make it fair for both ?

this is one of the outputs for javascript VM

Account 1: 0xca3[player1]

Commit phase 
—————————

Transaction cost : 85799 gas

Execution cost : 62927 gas

Reveal phase 
————

Transaction cost : 45485 gas

Execution cost :22613 gas

Account 2: 0x147 [player2]

Commit phase 
—————————

Transaction cost : 66397 gas

Execution cost : 43653 gas

Reveal phase 
————

Transaction cost : 45357 gas

Execution cost :22613 gas

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract rpsgame {

```
mapping (string => mapping(string => int)) scenarioMatrix;

address player1;
address player2;
uint currentGameCost = 0;
uint RevealTime;
bytes32 player1ChoiceHash;
bytes32 player2ChoiceHash;
string public player1Choice;
string public player2Choice;

function register (string choice, string randStr) payable notRegisteredyet()  sentCash(5 wei) {
    // players register , and input their (ether value >=5) and their choice + random String
    if(player1 == 0)
    player1=msg.sender;
    else if (player2 == 0)
    player2=msg.sender;
    if (msg.sender == player1)
          player1ChoiceHash = sha3(sha3(choice) ^ sha3(randStr));
    else if (msg.sender == player2)
        player2ChoiceHash =sha3(sha3(choice) ^ sha3(randStr)) ;

} 




function rpsgame() 
{   // constructor :executed only once , list all possible scenarios of the game 
    scenarioMatrix["rock"]["rock"] = 0;
    scenarioMatrix["rock"]["paper"] = 2;
    scenarioMatrix["rock"]["scissors"] = 1;
    scenarioMatrix["paper"]["rock"] = 1;
    scenarioMatrix["paper"]["paper"] = 0;
    scenarioMatrix["paper"]["scissors"] = 2;
    scenarioMatrix["scissors"]["rock"] = 2;
    scenarioMatrix["scissors"]["paper"] = 1;
    scenarioMatrix["scissors"]["scissors"] = 0;
}



modifier notRegisteredyet() {  // to make sure the that the same player doesn't register twice'

    if (msg.sender == player1 || msg.sender == player2)
     revert();
     else
      _;

}



 modifier sentCash(uint amount) {

 // checks that Ether value is >= 5
 if (msg.value < amount) {
    revert();
}
 //   its sets the decided amount of ether after updating what the first player entered. 
 //player2 can check that by press DisplayEther tab.

 if (player1 == 0) {
    currentGameCost = msg.value;
} 
else if (msg.value != currentGameCost) {
    revert();
}

_;

}



 function revealHand(string choice, string randStr)

{  //time to reveal the choices by input again the choice+random string and will checks
   //if hashedchoice+random string matches the initial ones.
     RevealTime == now;


    if (msg.sender == player1 && sha3(sha3(choice) ^ sha3(randStr)) == player1ChoiceHash)
        player1Choice = choice;
    if (msg.sender == player2 && sha3(sha3(choice) ^ sha3(randStr)) == player2ChoiceHash)
        player2Choice = choice;
}


 function play() returns (int w ){
     // time to find the winner , 0= tie , 1=player1 , 2=player2
        if (bytes(player1Choice).length != 0 && bytes(player2Choice).length != 0){

        int winner = scenarioMatrix[player1Choice][player2Choice];
        if (winner == 1)
            player1.transfer(this.balance);
        else if (winner == 2)
            player2.transfer(this.balance);

        else
        {
            player1.transfer(this.balance/2);
            player2.transfer(this.balance);
        }


        // to reset game 
       player1Choice = "";
        player2Choice = "";
        player1 = 0;
       player2 = 0;
       currentGameCost=0;
        return winner;
    }

   else if (now > RevealTime + 60)
    {
        // approx 1 mintue of waiting if only one player revealed,the ether goes directly to them.
        if (bytes(player1Choice).length != 0)
            player1.send(this.balance);
        else if (bytes(player2Choice).length != 0)
            player2.send(this.balance);
    }

   else
    return -1;
}



// getter function for player2 to see the amount of ether should be deposited


function DisplayEther () constant returns (uint amount) {

     return currentGameCost;
 }
```

}

Comment: It would be impossible to answer that without seeing the smart contract and the transactions. The gas cost could vary based on something as small as the number of zeros versus non-zeros in an address, or whether new values were being added to storage versus old values changed, etc. Without knowing the transactions and smart contract involved, it's impossible to speculate.

Comment: can i know what do you mean by zero or non -zeros?

Comment: @smarx , i have added the code , please check it :)

Comment: I literally mean the number 0 versus a different number (e.g. 1).

Comment: Completely unrelated to this question, note that your commit/reveal scheme is insecure. "paper" ^ "scissors" == "scissors" ^ "paper", so player 2 can selectively reveal either "paper" or "scissors" depending on what player 1 revealed. (In fact, either player can reveal _any_ move.) You can fix this by concatenating rather than XORing.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand you, to avoid this cheatable case i took the hash of each string so the next player cannot reveal the first player choice

Comment: I mean one player can just watch what the other reveals and then choose what to reveal themselves. In the "commit-reveal," they never had to actually commit.

Comment: but i made a condition already that it has to match the initial one entered in the commit phase

Comment: All that has to match is the XOR of the two strings, and XOR is commutative. So I can commit with "paper", "scissors" and then reveal with either "paper", "scissors" or "scissors", "paper," depending on which one will win. (I can also reveal "rock" if I just XOR that too.)

Comment: by XOR you mean this opreator [ ^ ] ?

Comment: Yes. That's the XOR operator.

Comment: i tried (.) and (+) and they don't seems to work :/

Comment: `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(choice, randStr))` should do the trick. Note that you also have to consider what happens if someone doesn't reveal. (The second player currently has no incentive to do so if they're going to lose.)  https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/16/flipping-a-coin-in-ethereum/ might help.

Comment: sha3 is not ok ?

Comment: sha3 is an old (deprecated) alias for keccak256. I believe it may be altogether gone in the latest compiler.

Comment: @smarx , i subistitut this line [ sha3(sha3(choice) ^ sha3(randStr));] with [keccak256(abi.encodePacked(choice, randStr))] however , how can i check the difference between sha3 and keccak256?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "check the difference between sha3 and keccak256". In Solidity, there is no difference between the two (except `sha3` is deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

The first player to call `register` bears the cost of changing `currentGameCost` from 0 to whatever payment was attached.

Changing a value in storage from a zero to a non-zero value costs 20,000 gas. This is approximately the difference between the gas costs of the two calls.